# How does Factory Reset Protection Lock work?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, factory-reset

I'm trying to bypass the Factory Reset Protection Lock on one of my phones running Android 6.0, but all of the tricks found on the net simply don't work. I basically tried two of them: Factory Reset from the Settings menu (this doesn't remove the lock) and unlocking the bootloader, which also doesn't work because I can't simply get the developer's options by pressing the compilation number several times. So I don't think I will remove the lock, but I'm just wondering how this security feature works.

Basically when you do a Factory Reset, you simply format /data/ and /cache/ partitions. So no user data is available on the phone after the process is done. So what's the difference between doing Factory Reset via Settings and via recovery mode? What other partitions are involved and what Android does to them in order to maintain the lock? If I formatted that partition (or partitions), would that remove the lock?